# Prisma ORM: How to update and set field1 value with field2 value from the same table?

Tags: node.js, prisma

In my Nodejs project using Prisma, I want to updateMany my table's records and set field1 with field2 value, but I couldn't find the way to do this. I can do this with getting the records first with `findMany` and then update them in a loop with `updateMany`.

Database Schema:

```
model myTable {
    id        String @id @default(uuid())
    field1    Int
    field2    Int
}
```

My Code:

```
// The above code not working
prisma.myTable.updateMany({
    where: {
        userId: 1234,
    },
    data: {
        someRandomField: 'xyz',
        field1: {
            set: {
                field2,
            }
        }
    }
})
```

In SQL It's possible with one query.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please share your schema file?

Comment: Hey @NurulSundarani, I just updated my question with the schema, It's just a table with two fields, I wanted to update field1 with field2 value like what we have in SQL: `UPDATE myTable SET field1=field2 WHERE id=xyz`

Comment: Hi @Reza as far as I know  you cannot do what you did using raw sql in Prisma, And you have to first fetch and then update the fields. or just use Prisma's [Raw database access](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access)